# What happens to a thread when it ends?

Tags: android, thread-safety

What happens to a thread once it hits the ends? Does it kill itself? or does it float around in memory taking up space? what exactly happens?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//do some stuff
...

//ok... did some stuff, now what?
}
}).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It finishes and all it's ThreadLocal objects become eligible for Garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It just simply ends like a normal piece of program. and Garbage Collector can recycle the memory it took. If you want the thread continues to run, you would use it with a while loop or so.